# Problema añadir datos ArrayList

Tags: java

Hola chicos os comento mi problema, tengo una clase que es Programador, de ella extiende otra clase que es líder. Dentro de líder tengo un ArrayList de Programadores entonces a la hora de dar de alta mi empleado y le indique que es líder lo que quiero es listar todos los programadores y a raíz de eso elegir el id de los que van a formar parte del grupo del líder que voy a dar de alta tengo esto:

Clase Programador:

```
public class Programador extends EmpTiempoCompleto implements Serializable {
    private String lenguajeProgramacion;
    private String esLider;

    public Programador(int idEmpleado, double salario, Date fecha_ini_contrato, Date fecha_fin_contrato, String nombre, String lenguajeProgramacion, String esLider) {
        super(idEmpleado, salario, fecha_ini_contrato, fecha_fin_contrato, nombre);
        this.lenguajeProgramacion = lenguajeProgramacion;
        this.esLider=esLider;
    }

    public String getLenguajeProgramacion() {
        return lenguajeProgramacion;
    }

    public String getEsLider() {
        return esLider;
    }

    public void setEsLider(String esLider) {
        this.esLider = esLider;
    }

    public void setLenguajeProgramacion(String lenguajeProgramacion) {
        this.lenguajeProgramacion = lenguajeProgramacion;
    }
}
```

Clase Lider:

```
public class Lider extends Programador implements Serializable{

    private ArrayList<Programador> list_programmer;

    public Lider(int idEmpleado, double salario, Date fecha_ini_contrato, Date fecha_fin_contrato, String nombre, String lenguajeProgramacion, String esLider, ArrayList<Programador> list_programmer) {
        super(idEmpleado, salario, fecha_ini_contrato, fecha_fin_contrato, nombre, lenguajeProgramacion, esLider);
        this.list_programmer = list_programmer;
    }

    public ArrayList<Programador> getList_programmer() {
        return list_programmer;
    }

    public void setList_programmer(ArrayList<Programador> list_programmer) {
        this.list_programmer = list_programmer;
    }

    public void addProgrammer(Programador list_programmer) {
        this.list_programmer.add(list_programmer);
    }
}
```

El punto en el que doy de alta:

```
 do {
    System.out.println("Es Lider este usuario?(S/N)");
    lider = MyInput.readString().toUpperCase();
    if(lider.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Debe introducir este dato.");
    }
}while (lider.isEmpty());
if(lider.equals("S")){
    salario = salario * 1.10;
    e1.listarProgramadores();
    do {
        System.out.println("Elige miembros de equipo uno por uno:");
        int idProgramador;
        ArrayList<Programador> programmers;
       programmers.add(idProgramador);
    }while(op = "N");
}else
```

La verdad no se muy bien como hacerlo para introducir los ids a ver si me podéis echar un cable , saludos!

Comment: Hola Peter, no tengo muy claro qué `Progamadores` quieres que se listen. ¿Quieres listarlos todos y que el usuario pueda escoger por `id`?

Comment: Hola David te comento, yo previamente he introducido una serie de programadores que tienen su id,salario etc. Entonces yo listo estos programadores con el fin de ver su id y de ver cuales están disponibles y lo que quiero es elegir uno, dos o n... para introducirlos dentro del arrayList de programadores que esta dentro de lider y estos formen parte del equipo de ese lider.

Comment: Hola de nuevo Peter. Si quieres buscar un `Programador` por `id` creo que te vendría mejor usar un [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), donde las claves sean los `id`  y los valores los `Programadores`. Si puedes cambiar la implementación, te simplificará las cosas.

Answer (score 0):

Hola voy a pasarte una respuesta, quizás te sirva, la hice media a las apuradas pero bueno, tené en cuenta que una vez que le das run as application, tenés que escribir sobre la consola el número de id que buscás.

Clase **Empleado**

```
    package com.soa.entities;

    import java.sql.Date;

    public class Empleado {

        private int idEmpleado;

        private double salario;
        private String nombre;
        private Date fechaIniContrato;
        private Date fechaFinContrato;

        public Empleado() {

        }

        public Empleado(int idEmpleado, double salario, String nombre, Date fechaIniContrato, Date fechaFinContrato) {
            super();
            this.idEmpleado = idEmpleado;
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.salario = salario;
            this.fechaIniContrato = fechaIniContrato;
            this.fechaFinContrato = fechaFinContrato;
        }

        public int getIdEmpleado() {
            return idEmpleado;
        }
        public void setIdEmpleado(int idEmpleado) {
            this.idEmpleado = idEmpleado;
        }
        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }
        public void setNombre(String nombre) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }
        public double getSalario() {
            return salario;
        }
        public void setSalario(double salario) {
            this.salario = salario;
        }
        public Date getFechaIniContrato() {
            return fechaIniContrato;
        }
        public void setFechaIniContrato(Date fechaIniContrato) {
            this.fechaIniContrato = fechaIniContrato;
        }
        public Date getFechaFinContrato() {
            return fechaFinContrato;
        }
        public void setFechaFinContrato(Date fechaFinContrato) {
            this.fechaFinContrato = fechaFinContrato;
        }

    }
```

Clase **Lider**
En esta clase no tuve tiempo de modificar las variables que declaraste con el guión bajo(_) habitualmente para declarar variables no estáticas de utuliza camelCase, osea empieza en minúsculas y luego mayúsculas.

```
    package com.soa.entities;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.sql.Date;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Lider extends Programador implements Serializable{

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5076867857967008095L;

        private static int cantidadProgramadores;

        private ArrayList<Programador> listProgrammer = new ArrayList<>();

        public Lider(int idEmpleado, double salario, Date fecha_ini_contrato, Date fecha_fin_contrato, String nombre, String lenguajeProgramacion, boolean esLider) {
            super(idEmpleado, salario, fecha_ini_contrato, fecha_fin_contrato, nombre, lenguajeProgramacion, esLider);

        }

        public ArrayList<Programador> getListProgrammer() {
            return listProgrammer;
        }

        public void setListProgrammer(ArrayList<Programador> listProgrammer) {
            this.listProgrammer = listProgrammer;
        }

        public void addProgrammer(Programador programmer) {
            this.listProgrammer.add(programmer);
            this.setCantidadProgramadores(this.getCantidadProgramadores() + 1);
        }

        public static int getCantidadProgramadores() {
            return cantidadProgramadores;
        }

        public static void setCantidadProgramadores(int cantidadProgramadores) {
            Lider.cantidadProgramadores = cantidadProgramadores;
        }
    }
```

Clase **Programador**

```
    package com.soa.entities;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.sql.Date;

    public class Programador extends Empleado implements Serializable {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String lenguajeProgramacion;
        private boolean esLider;

        public Programador() {

        }

        public Programador(int idEmpleado, double salario, Date fechaIniContrato, Date fechaFinContrato, String nombre, String lenguajeProgramacion, boolean esLider) {
            super(idEmpleado, salario,nombre, fechaIniContrato, fechaFinContrato);
            this.lenguajeProgramacion = lenguajeProgramacion;
            this.esLider=esLider;
        }

        public String getLenguajeProgramacion() {
            return lenguajeProgramacion;
        }

        public boolean getEsLider() {
            return esLider;
        }

        public void setEsLider(boolean esLider) {
            this.esLider = esLider;
        }

        public void setLenguajeProgramacion(String lenguajeProgramacion) {
            this.lenguajeProgramacion = lenguajeProgramacion;
        }
    }
```

Clase **Test** (Main)

```
package com.soa.view;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
import com.soa.entities.Lider;
import com.soa.entities.Programador;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* Creamos un lider */
        Lider lider = new Lider(10, 20, new Date(27 / 10 / 2007), new Date(27 / 10 / 2007), "Enrique", "Java", true);


        /* Creamos varios programadores */
        Programador programador1 = new Programador(1, 25, new Date(27 / 10 / 2007), new Date(27 / 10 / 2007), "Marcelo",
                "Java", false);
        Programador programador2 = new Programador(2, 25, new Date(27 / 10 / 2007), new Date(27 / 10 / 2007), "Pedro",
                "Java", false);
        Programador programador3 = new Programador(3, 25, new Date(27 / 10 / 2007), new Date(27 / 10 / 2007), "José",
                "Java", false);
        Programador programador4 = new Programador(4, 25, new Date(27 / 10 / 2007), new Date(27 / 10 / 2007), "Pampuro",
                "Java", false);
        Programador programador5 = new Programador(5, 25, new Date(27 / 10 / 2007), new Date(27 / 10 / 2007), "Treluco",
                "Java", false);
        Programador programador6 = new Programador(6, 25, new Date(27 / 10 / 2007), new Date(27 / 10 / 2007), "Portillo",
                "Java", false);

        /* Adjuntamos a la lista que trae la clase */
        lider.addProgrammer(programador1);
        lider.addProgrammer(programador2);
        lider.addProgrammer(programador3);
        lider.addProgrammer(programador4);
        lider.addProgrammer(programador5);

        /* Usamos esta instancia para escribir escribir sobre la consola y hacer la prueba, apenas le pones run escribi el número de id a buscar y enter */
        Scanner inputConsole = new Scanner(System.in);

        /* Si la cantidad de programadores es menor igual a 5 se pueden seguir agregando a este equipo */
        if (Lider.getCantidadProgramadores() <= 5) {

            /* Mientras el getLider() sea true va a seguir en el bucle */
            while (lider.getEsLider()) {
                System.out.println("Todavía puede agregarse programadores.");

                /* iteramos por cada objeto del ArrayList */
                for (Programador item : lider.getListProgrammer()) {

                    Programador programadorTemporal = null;

                    if(item.getIdEmpleado() == 5) {

                        /* Si un objeto cumple con la condición se termina de crear un programador y se le asignan los datos */
                        programadorTemporal = new Programador();
                        programadorTemporal.setIdEmpleado(item.getIdEmpleado());
                        programadorTemporal.setNombre(item.getNombre());
                        System.out.println("El empleado correspondiente al id "+ programadorTemporal.getIdEmpleado()+", su nombre es: "+ programadorTemporal.getNombre());

                    /* Si no encuentra ningún id te muestra esto */
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("no hay coincidencia de id");
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        /* Si sobrepasa la cantidad máxima entra acá */
        } else {
            System.out.println("No pueden agregarse más a este líder");
            lider.setEsLider(false);
        }

    }

}
```

**Escribí en pantalla el id buscado y fijate si va todo bien.**

**Te dejo un pantallazo con el resultado, la hice muy en el aire, pero ojalá que te sirva.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @peter Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Mmmm no me ha funcionado o no lo he sabido interpretar yo, te comento. Tengo una clase Programadores donde ya hay dados de alta x programadores, y tengo una funcion para listar los programadores. Lo que quiero es decirle al dar de alta un lider que elija por id que programdores quieren que formen parte de su equipo en plan el programador con id1,id2 y id3 y añadirlos al equipo de ese programador.